# Populate a column from one table with the column value from another table with factorys

Tags: laravel, laravel-8, factory

Table ItemAA

```
id_aa
name_aa
```

Table ItemBB

```
id_bb
name_bb
```

RelashionShips One To One

**Goal to be achieved**: populate the **name_aa** column (ItemAA table) with the same value as the **name_bb** column (ItemBB table), randomly

Factory with unsuccessful attempt:

```
public function definition()
{
    return [
        'id_aa' => ItemBBModel::inRandomOrder()->first(), // Works great
        'name_aa' => ItemBBModel::inRandomOrder()->get(['name_bb']) // doesn't work correctly
    ];
}
```

EDITED: The name_bb must belong to the same row as the id_bb

Example:

```
id_bb     name_bb
1          one 
2          two 
3          three
```

Expected:

```
'id_aa' => 2
'name_aa' => two
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

we can update it a little bit to make it works

```
public function definition()
{
$randomOrder = Offer::inRandomOrder()->first();
    return [
        'id_aa' => $randomOrder->id_bb, 
        'name_aa' => $randomOrder->name_bb
    ];
}
```